# Trying to understand BorderLayout and internal padding

Tags: java, swing, padding, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

The assignment is to add code to create a GUI that allows the user to order pizza and select toppings.  I'm stuck on the positioning of the Calculate and Exit Buttons, which should go below the `JTextField`.

I am also trying to figure out how to decrease internal padding in the `JCheckBox` panel, as it seems the GUI may need to do this also.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PizzaOrderFrame extends JFrame {

    JRadioButton smallRadioButton, mediumRadioButton, largeRadioButton;
    JCheckBox sausageCheckBox, pepperoniCheckBox, salamiCheckBox, 
            olivesCheckBox, mushroomsCheckBox, anchoviesCheckBox;
    JTextField priceTextField;
    JButton calculateButton, exitButton;

    PizzaOrderFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setTitle("Pizza Calculator");
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        smallRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Small");
        mediumRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Medium");
        largeRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Large");
        ButtonGroup sizeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        sizeGroup.add(smallRadioButton);
        sizeGroup.add(mediumRadioButton);
        sizeGroup.add(largeRadioButton);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Size"));
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        buttonPanel.add(smallRadioButton);
        buttonPanel.add(mediumRadioButton);
        buttonPanel.add(largeRadioButton);

        sausageCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Sausage");
        pepperoniCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni");
        salamiCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Salami");
        olivesCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Olives");
        mushroomsCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Mushrooms");
        anchoviesCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Anchovies");

        JPanel chkBoxPanel = new JPanel();
        chkBoxPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Toppings"));
        chkBoxPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        chkBoxPanel.add(sausageCheckBox, getConstraints(0, 0));
        chkBoxPanel.add(olivesCheckBox, getConstraints(1, 0));
        chkBoxPanel.add(pepperoniCheckBox, getConstraints(0, 1));
        chkBoxPanel.add(salamiCheckBox, getConstraints(0, 2));
        chkBoxPanel.add(mushroomsCheckBox, getConstraints(1, 1));
        chkBoxPanel.add(anchoviesCheckBox, getConstraints(1, 2));

        priceTextField = new JTextField(10);
        priceTextField.setEnabled(false);

        JPanel pricePanel = new JPanel();
        pricePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        pricePanel.add(new JLabel("Price"));
        pricePanel.add(priceTextField);

        calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        ButtonGroup bottomButtons = new ButtonGroup();
        bottomButtons.add(calculateButton);
        bottomButtons.add(exitButton);

        JPanel buttonPanel2 = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        buttonPanel2.add(calculateButton);
        buttonPanel2.add(exitButton);

        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(chkBoxPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(pricePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(buttonPanel2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        setSize(270, 280);
    }

    // helper method for getting a GridBagConstraints object
    private GridBagConstraints getConstraints(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
        c.gridx = x;
        c.gridy = y;
        c.ipadx = 0;
        c.ipady = 0;
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            PizzaOrderFrame frame = new PizzaOrderFrame();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Need assistance please!!!"* Need a question please! *"I have not added code for the action events.."* Good, but this is a layout problem, so there should be no actions added in the first place. Post a [mre].

Comment: Me *"Post a minimal reproducible example."* I have edited the question to include code that has nothing extraneous, but compiles and runs as is. Please copy it into a new project in your IDE and confirm it displays the problem (another important aspect of an MRE).

Answer (score 1):

> ..how to decrease internal padding in the `JCheckBox` panel..

Decrease the size of the insets! E.G.

```
c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
```

Could be:

```
c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0); // try other values
```

> I'm stuck on the positioning of the Calculate and Exit Buttons, which should go below the `JTextField`.

Note that **layouts can be [combined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).** It is rare that a complete GUI view uses a single layout.

In this case, I might create a `JPanel` with a single column `GridLayout`, add the price/text field panel to it, then another panel for the buttons. Then add that grid layout panel to the `SOUTH` / `PAGE_END` of the border layout.

---

The result of doing both those (and calling `pack()` instead of `setSize(..)`, which is a guess) is as follows:

[image]

Comment: BTW - put the panel with toppings in the `CENTER` rather than the `EAST` to have it stretch (width wise) to the available space. I would also recommend using a layout / constraint that positions the label / text field & the buttons, in the center of the available width.